# What is the song that plays every time Kikyo appears with Inuyasha?

Tags: music, inuyasha

Does anyone know the music track or OST that appears every time Kikyo appears with Inuyasha? The music only plays for a little while and has a sad ring to it. I tried looking for it for month but I couldn't find it anywhere. It plays at Episode 47 at 16:27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Kikyo theme song is called [Miko Kikyo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bw8-xsF8X5w).

The song was released as the 30th track of [Inuyasha OST 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BD2TYQ).